# Improve the speed to process many many small files

Tags: c, linux, performance, file

We have an app needs to process many many small files(10million~100million files, all 1KB~2KB size) on startup.

These files reside under many nested dirs under one root dir.

What we need to do is very simple: read the first 128 bytes of the file, and check the validity of the file(the check itself is very cheap).

Current we just recursively read the dir and read the file one by one, it almost causes us 6 hours to complete the process.

We tried multiple processes, and the time reduced to 4 hours when we use all the cores.

We tried linux native Aio, and the time reduced to 3~4 hours.

Is there any other ways to reduce the process time?

Comment: Maybe in combination with **sync**?

Comment: You are likely limited by filesystem IO operations - using all cores may actually slow you down, I would test with different numbers of cores to see what's optimal. Is there away to affect how these files are generated? Can they be dumped in chunks to less files? Do you have time to concatenate some while others are being generated? Givinig the full process will allow more flexibility for answers., and also ensure this isn't an XY problem.

Comment: How was the tasks split between the processes/threads? Have you tried creating a list/array of file paths and then split this array into  chunks so that each chunk would be processed by a separate thread?

Comment: @JoopEggen Any info on sync?

Comment: @kabanus the files are generated by other systems. We cannot change that..

Comment: @AlexLop. yes, I have process 1 process dir 00~09, process 2 process dir 10~19, something like this, to ensure different process process different files.

Comment: `sync` is a well documented tool to normally synchronize remote directories be composing a transfer list. So to detect changes. Without sync guru to abuse sync, you might maintain a list of files and modification dates yourself. That was all I wanted to say, thinking you knew sync. (Alternatives) Conventional file systems have problems with large directories. Before trying something new, you could use a RAM disk and alias some directory to it. Faster startup, but needing to copy the RAM disk. But with SSDs nowadays...

Comment: Linux systems limit the number of file descriptors that any one process may open to 1024 per process. After the directory server has exceeded the file descriptor limit of 1024 per process, any new process and worker threads will be blocked. Use the 
  `ulimit`  command to set the file descriptor limit to `unlimited`

Comment: @JoopEggen Are you talking about `rsync`?

Comment: @Shawn oh sorry, of course.

Comment: @majidhajibaba I close the fd once the read is done. besides I updated the open files limit to 100000;

Comment: How big is the disk partition? If it is very small, it may be much faster to copy data into the RAM. Alternatively, it could be also more efficient to pack all the files to a huge one if this is possible. Consider moving data to (NVMe) SSDs which are much much faster for this kind of operations (see [IOPS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS)). The file system probably matters a lot too.

Comment: Make multiple filesystems, preferably on multiple NVME SSDs under the root directory to spread the load.

Comment: This sounds like a problem you need to break down and profile... What time is spent in each part of the process (enumerate files, read 128 bytes, "_check validity_", etc...). Can you define "_very cheap_"? Work with a smaller dataset that takes ~15-30 seconds to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind testing the following `verifier.c`?

```c
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0 */
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Singly-linked list of paths. */
struct path_list {
    struct path_list *next;
    int               err;
    char              path[];
};

/* File content verifier.  Returns 0 if OK, errno error code otherwise. */
static int verify_data(const unsigned char *data, const size_t size)
{
    /*
     * TODO!
    */

    (void)data; (void)size; /* Remove; these just silence warnings about unused parameters. */

    return 0;
}


static inline void free_path_list(struct path_list *list)
{
    while (list) {
        struct path_list *curr = list;

        list = list->next;

        curr->next = NULL;
        curr->err  = -1;
        free(curr);
    }
}

/* Number of descriptors excluded in the calculations */
#ifndef  RESERVE_DESCRIPTORS
#define  RESERVE_DESCRIPTORS  10
#endif

/* Minimum number of descriptors for nftw() */
#ifndef  MINIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS
#define  MINIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS  16
#endif

/* Maximum number of descriptors for nftw()
   - recommended number is twice the maximum depth of the tree. */
#ifndef  MAXIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS
#define  MAXIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS  256
#endif

static int   verify_tree_add(const char *, const struct stat *, int);
static void *verify_tree_worker(void *);

static pthread_t        *verify_worker  = NULL;
static size_t            verify_workers = 0;
static unsigned long     verify_count_ok = 0;
static unsigned long     verify_count = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t   verify_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t    verify_more = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static struct path_list *verify_list = NULL;    /* Paths to be verified */
static struct path_list *verify_fail = NULL;    /* Paths that failed the check */
static int               verify_done = 0;      /* Set when path buffer completed */

/* Verify all regular files in the specified tree using 'workers' threads.
   Returns the list of files that failed verification.
   Always sets errno: to zero if success, to nonzero if error.
*/
static struct path_list *verify_tree(const char *root, const size_t workers)
{
    struct path_list *retval;
    pthread_attr_t    attrs;
    struct rlimit     limit;
    long              maxfd;
    size_t            i;
    int               result;

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (!root || *root == '\0' || workers < 1) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Maximum number of file descriptors */
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit) == -1)
        return NULL;

    /* If limited, try to up the soft limit to the hard limit. */
    if (limit.rlim_max != RLIM_INFINITY && limit.rlim_cur < limit.rlim_max) {
        limit.rlim_cur = limit.rlim_max;
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit);
    }

    /* Find out the maximum number of file descriptors. */
    maxfd = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
    if (limit.rlim_cur != RLIM_INFINITY && (long)limit.rlim_cur < maxfd)
        maxfd = (long)limit.rlim_cur;

    /* Subtract the number of reserved descriptors and those needed by workers */
    if (maxfd > (long)(workers + RESERVE_DESCRIPTORS))
        maxfd -= workers + RESERVE_DESCRIPTORS;
    /* and limit to the configured range. */
    if (maxfd < MINIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS)
        maxfd = MINIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS;
    if (maxfd > MAXIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS)
        maxfd = MAXIMUM_NFTW_DESCRIPTORS;

    /* Initialize worker information. */
    verify_workers = 0;
    verify_worker  = malloc(workers * sizeof verify_worker[0]);
    if (!verify_worker) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    pthread_mutex_init(&verify_lock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&verify_more, NULL);
    verify_list = NULL;
    verify_fail = NULL;
    verify_done = 0;

    /* Clear the counters. */
    verify_count = 0;
    verify_count_ok = 0;

    /* Threads need very little stack. */
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 2*PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);
    /* Start the worker threads. */
    for (i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
        result = pthread_create(verify_worker + verify_workers, &attrs, verify_tree_worker, NULL);
        if (!result)
            verify_workers++;
    }
    /* Discard the thread creation attribute set. */
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    /* No workers started? */
    if (verify_workers < 1) {
        free(verify_worker);
        verify_workers = 0;
        verify_worker = NULL;
        verify_done = -1;
        pthread_cond_destroy(&verify_more);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&verify_lock);
        /* Insufficient resources */
        errno = EAGAIN;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Start directory scan. */
    result = ftw(root, verify_tree_add, maxfd);
    if (result) {
        /* Failed; abort. Save errno. */
        if (result == -1)
            result = errno;

        /* Signal threads to cancel work. */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
        verify_done = -1;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&verify_more);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&verify_lock);

        /* Reap worker threads. */
        for (i = 0; i < verify_workers; i++)
            pthread_join(verify_worker[i], NULL);

        /* Grab the failed paths list. */
        retval = verify_fail;
        verify_fail = NULL;

        /* Discard any paths not verified. */
        free_path_list(verify_list);
        verify_list = NULL;

        /* Cleanup. */
        free(verify_worker);
        verify_workers = 0;
        verify_worker = NULL;
        pthread_cond_destroy(&verify_more);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&verify_lock);

        errno = result;
        return retval;
    }

    /* Success. Signal threads that no more paths will be added. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
    verify_done = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&verify_more);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&verify_lock);

    /* Reap worker threads. */
    for (i = 0; i < verify_workers; i++)
        pthread_join(verify_worker[i], NULL);

    /* Will return the failed paths list. */
    retval = verify_fail;
    verify_fail = NULL;

    /* Prepend all unprocessed paths -- should be none! -- to failed list. */
    while (verify_list) {
        struct path_list *curr = verify_list;
        verify_list = curr->next;
        curr->next = retval;
        retval = curr;
    }

    /* Cleanup. */
    free(verify_worker);
    verify_workers = 0;
    verify_worker = NULL;
    pthread_cond_destroy(&verify_more);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&verify_lock);

    /* Success. */
    errno = 0;
    return retval;
}

/* Add regular files to the work pool. */
static int verify_tree_add(const char *path, const struct stat *info, int typeflag)
{
    struct path_list  *item;
    size_t             path_len;

    /* Ignore all but regular files. */
    if (typeflag != FTW_F)
        return 0;

    /* Ignore zero-sized files. */
    if (!info->st_size)
        return 0;

    /* Ignore NULL and empty paths, although they shouldn't happen. */
    if (!path || !*path)
        return 0;

    path_len = strlen(path);
    item = malloc(sizeof (struct path_list) + path_len + 1);
    if (!item)
        return ENOMEM;

    /* Copy the path, including the end-of-string '\0'. */
    memcpy(item->path, path, path_len + 1);

    /* This path item should be OK. */
    item->err = 0;

    /* Prepend to the path list. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
    item->next = verify_list;
    verify_list = item;
    /* Signal a waiting worker. */
    pthread_cond_signal(&verify_more);
    /* Add to count. */
    verify_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&verify_lock);

    return 0;
}

/* Work pool worker thread. */
static void *verify_tree_worker(void *unused __attribute__((unused)))
{
    unsigned char     data[128];
    size_t            have;
    ssize_t           bytes;
    int               fd, result;
    struct path_list *curr;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
    while (verify_done >= 0) {

        /* No paths in the list? */
        if (!verify_list) {
            /* All done? */
            if (verify_done)
                break;

            /* No, wait for a new path. */
            pthread_cond_wait(&verify_more, &verify_lock);
            continue;
        }

        /* Extract path from the list. */
        curr = verify_list;
        verify_list = curr->next;

        /* Release the mutex for the duration of the verification work. */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&verify_lock);

        /* Open the file to be verified. */
        fd = open(curr->path, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
        if (fd == -1) {
            curr->err = errno;

            /* Append to failed list. */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
            curr->next = verify_fail;
            verify_fail = curr;
            continue;
        }

        /* Read the initial part of the file, or entire file if it fits in the buffer. */
        have = 0;
        while (have < sizeof data) {
            bytes = read(fd, data + have, sizeof data - have);
            if (bytes > 0) {
                have += bytes;
            } else
            if (bytes == 0) {
                /* All read */
                break;
            } else
            if (bytes != -1) {
                /* Bug. Mark as an I/O error. */
                curr->err = EIO;
                have = 0;
                break;
            } else
            if (errno != EINTR && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                curr->err = errno;
                have = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (close(fd) == -1) {
            /* This does not normally occur, but let's be thorough. */
            have = 0;
            if (!curr->err)
                curr->err = errno;
        }

        /* Empty file or error? */
        if (!have) {
            /* Append to failed list. */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
            curr->next = verify_fail;
            verify_fail = curr;
            continue;
        }

        /* Verify file contents. */
        result = verify_data(data, have);
        if (result) {
            /* Append to failed list. */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
            curr->err = result;
            curr->next = verify_fail;
            verify_fail = curr;
            continue;
        }

        /* Verification successful. */
        free(curr);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&verify_lock);
        verify_count_ok++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&verify_lock);

    return NULL;
}

static int parse_size(const char *src, size_t *to)
{
    const char    *end;
    unsigned long  val;

    if (!src)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    errno = 0;
    end = src;
    val = strtoul(src, (char **)(&end), 0);
    if (errno)
        return errno;
    if (end == src)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    while (*end == '\t' || *end == '\n' || *end == '\v' ||
           *end == '\f' || *end == '\r' || *end == ' ')
        end++;

    if (*end)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    if ((unsigned long)(size_t)(val) != val)
        return errno = ERANGE;

    if (to)
        *to = (size_t)val;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct path_list *list, *curr;
    size_t            threads;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[2], "--help")) {
        const char *self = (argc > 0 && argv[0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DIRECTORY THREADS\n", self);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program scans all regular files in DIRECTORY\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "and all its subdirectories, using THREADS threads\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "in parallel.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_size(argv[2], &threads) || threads < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of threads.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    list = verify_tree(argv[1], threads);
    if (errno) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Verification failed: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        for (curr = list; curr; curr = curr->next)
            printf("  %s: (%s)\n", curr->path, strerror(curr->err));
        free_path_list(list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (list) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Verification complete: %lu of %lu files ok.\n", verify_count_ok, verify_count);
        for (curr = list; curr; curr = curr->next)
            printf("  %s: (%s)\n", curr->path, strerror(curr->err));
        free_path_list(list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Verified all %lu files successfully!\n", verify_count_ok);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To compile, I recommend using

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 verifier.c -lpthread -o verifier
```

To run, use something like

```bash
./verifier /tree/with/files 64
```

where the first parameter is the directory tree to verify, and the second parameter is the number of worker threads to use.

The above program implements a simple thread pool -based single-process multi-threaded verifier.  (You should implement the actual data verification in the `verify_data()` function; for now, it assumes that if the file can be read, it is okay.  Note the `verify_tree_add()` function ignores empty files; you may wish to remove that check.  It was just easier for me to test the program this way.)

The main thread does the directory tree scanning using [`ftw()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftw.3.html), with the callback function extracting the full path, and adding to a list of paths to be opened and examined.

Each worker thread grabs the next path from the list, opens the file, reads the first 128 bytes (or the entire file, if the file is smaller), and verifies the contents.  If there is an error, the path is added to the failed paths list (that is returned to the caller); otherwise freed.

The idea behind this approach is that most of the worker threads will be blocking in a `read()` call, allowing the kernel to optimize the I/O request order and maximize the number of pages in flight, hopefully.

This is not at all optimized, and you might need to add additional guards (not letting the path list grow unbounded), but the underlying pattern should allow you to maximize the throughput.

(A similar pattern can be used in e.g. mail transfer agents when saving new messages to Maildir mailboxes, where each message is a separate file.  To ensure each file has hit the storage device, `fsync()` (or at least `fdatasync()`) needs to be called on the descriptor, but this can take quite a while.  Having a worker thread do the save and block on the `fsync()`/`fdatasync()` call allows the mail transfer agent to process other messages in the meanwhile.  It makes a huge difference in throughput.)

For testing, I compared

```bash
sudo sh -c 'sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; sync'
time  find /usr -type f -ls > /dev/null
```

which took about 30 seconds real time; and

```bash
sudo sh -c 'sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; sync'
time  ./verifier /usr 60
```

which took about 50 seconds real time.

In both commands, the `sudo` part clears page table cache (see [man 5 proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) section `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` for details), so both situations correspond when the computer has NOT cached any of the file contents yet, and is relatively quiescent wrt. I/O (the `sync` part).

Running cache-hot, the two commands take about 8 and 30 seconds, respectively.

(For testing, I used a verifier that checked if the first byte was 0x1c and the last read byte 0xfe, to ensure the compiler did not optimize anything away.  In other words, these tests did read the initial 128 bytes, or the entire file if smaller.)

This is a HP EliteBook 820 G1 laptop with Intel i5-4200U processor and a Samsung SSD, with 989610 (non-empty) files under `/usr`.  Obviously, SSDs far outperform spinning-disk storage especially for this kind of workload (small files, i.e. lots of small I/O transfer blocks), but three hours (or longer) for 100-200 million files sounds excessive to me.